# Is there a way to localise my robot using a combination of the navigation stack and robot localization package

Tags: localization, navigation, ros-melodic, raspberrypi, 2d-pose-estimate

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ROS melodic on a Raspberry Pi 3.

Basically I need to keep track of the robot as it travels. Using the ROS navigation stack I can track where the robot is, but I have to manually give it the initial pose. I would like to do this with GPS and an IMU. I'll be using the robot in the presence of a magnetic field so I don't think the IMU will give correct data, so I imagine I would need to use this in combination with a lidar scanner. I'm quite new to ROS so any direction would be quite helpful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/370243/is-there-a-way-to-localise-my-robot-using-a-combination-of-the-navigation-stack-and-robot-localization-package/) by [liambroek](https://answers.ros.org/users/68649/liambroek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2021-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use robot_localization package, the link below is a similar topic fusing IMU and GPS.

https://answers.ros.org/question/200071/how-to-fuse-imu-gps-using-robot_localization/

---

Originally posted by [AmirSaman](https://answers.ros.org/users/64433/amirsaman/) with karma: 130 on 2021-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1